# add text comments to a datatable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app where user is able to add text comment to a table.

I created a dataframe with 3 columns: `num`, `id` and `val`. I want my shiny app to do the following:

1. select an value from id column (selectInput).
2. add text comment in a text box (textInput)
3. click on an action button
4. A new column called `comment` is created in the data table, text comments are added to the comment column in the row where id equals the value selected.

My shiny app code is below. When I select an value from selectinput, add some comment in the text box and click on `add comment' button, my shiny app window shut down by itself.

Does anyone know why that happens?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    df = data.frame(num=1:10, id=LETTERS[1:10], val=rnorm(10)) 
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(2, selectInput(inputId = 'selectID',
                                  label = 'Select ID2',
                                  choices = LETTERS[1:10],
                                  selected='',
                                  multiple=TRUE)),
            column(6, textInput(inputId = 'comment', 
                                label ='Please add comment in the text box:', 
                                value = "", width = NULL,
                                placeholder = NULL)),
            column(2, actionButton(inputId = "button", 
                                   label = "Add Comment"))
        ),
        fluidRow (
            column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('data') ) 
        )           
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        observeEvent(input$button, {
            df[id==input$selectID, 'Comment']=input$comment
        })

        output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(df, 
                          options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
                          lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
        })


    }

    shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The column `id` is not recognized as a column of the data.frame `df` in `df[id == input$selectId, "Comment]`, replacing `id` by `df$id`  fixes the error.
2. In order to rerender the datatable after updating `df`, `df` should be a reactive object.
3. To handle multiple selected `id`'s in the selectInput `selectId`, you might want to replace `df$id == input$selectId` by `df$id %in% input$selectId`

This updated server function should help you with these issues:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## make df reactive
  df_current <- reactiveVal(df)

  observeEvent(input$button, {

      req(df_current())

      ## update df by adding comments
      df_new <- df_current()
      df_new[df_current()$id %in% input$selectID, "Comment"] <- input$comment

      df_current(df_new)

  })

  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({

      req(df_current())

      DT::datatable(df_current(), 
          options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
              lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 20), pageLength = 5))
  })
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Yes, this works for this example. However, in my actually app,  `df` is actually a reactive dataframe, from `dat <- reactive(...)`.  I replaced `df` with `dat()`. But it did not work.  Do you know why it does not work? Sorry, I should have put the whole actual case as the example. @Joris Chau

Comment: If `df` is a reactive object according to `df <- reactive(...)` its value cannot be modified with `df(df_new)` as with a `reactiveVal` object. You could define instead `df <- eventReactive(c(input$comments, other inputs), {...})`, or use the reactiveVal/observeEvent construction above. Maybe you could edit your question to include the reactive definition of `df`?

Comment: Thank you! I have posted another question for this.  Here is the link: 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515650/how-to-add-comment-to-a-reactive-data-table-in-shiny       Thank you again for your help with this.  @Joris Chau

Comment: I added a response at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515650/how-to-add-comment-to-a-reactive-data-table-in-shiny